# I want to create a interactive bar-chart in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho. I want to create a interactive bar-chart. so that I can click on a bar in that chart and the other report contents get changed accordingly. I am not able to do this in User Console. Is it possible to do it using User console? or some other way ?

Answer (score 0):

It honestly depends on if you are using the Enterprise Edition (paid) or the Community Edition (free).

In the Enterprise Edition, there is an included Dashboard Creator and Editor that allows you to do what you are describing - here is a link that explains how to do content linking in Enterprise Edition Dashboards: [Enterprise Edition Content Linking](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0L0/120/040/030)

If you are using the Community Edition, I recommend checking out the CTools add-on for creating dashboards: [Pentaho CTools](http://community.pentaho.com/ctools/)